# Assets not appearing in asset browser of a specific .blend

Tags: asset-browser

I have a .blend I am working in when I open the asset browser only the native assets appear. But if I switch to another .blend to work in, all of my assets appear. (I can see the categories I have created but there is nothing in them in the .blend with the issue. Any ideas as to what is different about this problematic .blend? Using Blender 3.5

Comment: Hello ! Check out the asset library category. In 3.5 it is set to "All" by default. You can change it to "current file"

Comment: I think I figured it out. The .blend file I was working in was also in the asset library file path and I think that is what confused it. Once I moved the file out the assets reappeared.